# python none value return

Tags: python, qt, focus

```
class MyWindow():

    class Filter(QtCore.QObject) :

        def eventFilter(self, widget, event):                         
            return event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut

    def __init__(self, ui) :
        self.ui = ui

    def mycode (self) :
        myvalue = float(self.ui.myvalueEdit.text()) 
        self._filter = self.Filter()    
        print (self.ui.myvalueEdit.installEventFilter(self._filter))
```

I'm trying to intercept the `focusEvent`, It's enought for me know that it changes. In this code I'm trying to read the return value of the `eventFilter` but I receive always the `None` value!

Comment: You're printing the return value of `installEventFilter`, not `eventFilter`.

Comment: Why are you trying to print the return value of `.installEventFilter` (the last line)? You should not expect anything there.. Instead put your print statement within `def eventFilter(..)` -- after that check for condition but before return.

Comment: The question is not quite clear. I don't think he could have mistaken `eventFilter` with installEventFilter` seems they are not even methods of the same class...But if he does, here is his problem.

Answer (score 1):

The method installEventFilter doesn't return anything, which is why you are getting None. Your eventFilter method is a callback that will be called when an event happens.

The return value of eventFilter is suppose to indicate whether or not you have handled the event. That is, you return True if you don't want any other object to handle the event in question. That is why you can't just return True, it will consume the event, you must handle any event yourself that you return True for.

```
class MyWindow(QtCore.QObject):

    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):                         
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut or event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusIn:
            print("Focus Changed!")
            print("Value I want to save is: " + widget.toPlainText())
            # Put the code you want to do here!
            return True 
        return False 

    def __init__(self, ui) :
        self.ui = ui

    def mycode (self) :
        myvalue = float(self.ui.myvalueEdit.text())   
        self.ui.myvalueEdit.installEventFilter(self)
```

Comment: I'd check the focus status, because I need to save some .ui values. In this case the solution sould be change the print("focus") code with something as return (?)

Comment: If you are just trying to check whether a widget has focus or not, then you can use the method hasFocus like this `print(self.ui.myvalueEdit.hasFocus())` If you are trying to run some code when an item gets focus, you'll need the event filter like what you've done.

Comment: Basically, what are you trying to do? Are you trying to check if an element has focus, and do something. Or are you trying to do something every time an element gets focus?

Comment: I'm trying  to do something every time an element gets focus (focus changed)

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer to give you a little more direction. Think about it this way, every time an event occurs, the eventFilter method will run. So in that method is where you would want to trigger the things that happen on focus change.

Comment: First thank you very much for your time Aaron. In your last case, can I check by self.ui.myvalueEdit.installEventFilter(self._filter) if the focus change?  Because I need to save the .ui fields when the test on QEvent.FocusOut etc. return True (this is my big problem).

Comment: Calling installEventFilter doesn't check anything. This is something you do once in order to set up the eventFilter on the UI element. The code that saves the .ui fields should be done in the eventFilter method, right where I put the comment to "Put the code you want to do here"

Comment: Okay, I tested to save the .ui value  where you put the comment, but without succes. (for this reason I thought at installEvenFilter)
For example, for saving only the "self.ui.myvalueEdit" value
I tried to read it with MyWindow.ui.myvalueEdit but it is not correct, I can read it only in the Mywindow Class as "self.ui.myvalueEdit" . maybe I'm missing something other

Comment: The Filter class will not have access to any other class members (ex: self.ui.myvalueEdit). But the widget parameter is the Widget that the events are occurring on (that would be myvalueEdit), I provided an update showing how you would print the value of the widget that focus was changed on (assuming it is a QTextEdit).

Comment: Thank you very much Aaron! My main purpose is to update one existing .ini file with the following code iniSettings.set('Section_One', 'string_val', my_val) for example where I can get my_val with my_val= widget.toPlainText()
Because the Filter class will not have access to MyWindow class I can't obtain information (I have not idea) about the other two values called in iniSettings.set() 
That's why it would be convenient to receive only the "return true" by eventFilter

Comment: If you absolutely need access to the member variables, then it shouldn't be a separate class. Just make MyWindow the eventFilter. I edited the answer. Now you'll have access all the member variables of MyWindow inside of the eventFilter method.